# Convertiing Avro to dask dataframe

Tags: dask

I am pretty new to Dask and had most of my files in Avro (migrated from PySpark). I tried using intake_avro (sequence), managed to read and does a take(1) showing the right data.

As I have quite a number of columns with 'None' and when I convert to dataframe it always gives me

***ValueError: Cannot convert non-finite values (NA or inf) to integer***

I am not sure whether I am doing right?

Comment: could you share the code?

Comment: This doesn't sound like a problem with avro loading as such, but bag->dataframe conversion. Perhaps the question would be better phrased if you made the input from simple dicts, so we can show you what to do.

Comment: @moshevi import intake
source = intake.open_avro_sequence('/path/*.avro')